# ORACLE ROWNUM Function (Using Pagination Page)

Tags: php, oracle, pagination

I still confused with the ROWNUM oracle function.

Last time I using LIMIT in MySQL function worked like this :

```
$page -= 1;
$per_page = 3;
$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$first_btn = true;
$last_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;

$sql = ... WHERE ... LIMIT $start, $per_page;
```

But now how can I use ROWNUM in ORACLE ?

```
$sql = ... WHERE ... ROWNUM $start, $per_page;
```

I using this because I have the pagination page.

Anyone please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, Rownum values are assigned only after the filtering stage of the query, So you must put it as a inline view. like,

```
select *
  from (select col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1 ASC) RowNumber 
       FROM table)
 where rownumber between 1 and 10
```

Or

```
select *
  from (select col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1 ASC) RowNumber 
       FROM TABLE)
 WHERE RowNumber > 1 AND RowNumber < 10;
```

Comment: I tried, but when I open the next page, it wasn't load the data.

Comment: Please post your query.

Comment: Here its : SELECT P.PRODUCTION_STATUS, P.DATE_ADDED, P.FORM_NO, P.MODEL_NO, M.MODEL_NO, rownum 
         from SEIAPPS_PRODUCTION_STATUS P, SEIAPPS_MODEL M

Comment: I tried with just 1 table it works, but when I add 1 table it show errors : Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: @user2806837, you are using `rownum` whereas Dba's suggested solution uses the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function.

Comment: You probably just need to use an alias for rownum, e.g. `ROWNUM AS RowNumber`

Comment: just try like this,
 SELECT * FROM 
 (
      SELECT P.PRODUCTION_STATUS, P.DATE_ADDED, P.FORM_NO, P.MODEL_NO, M.MODEL_NO, ROWNUM rn
      FROM   SEIAPPS_PRODUCTION_STATUS P, SEIAPPS_MODEL M
      WHERE  m.COL_NAME = p.COL_NAME
 )
 WHERE RN >= 1 RN <= 10;